# Message passing between 2 instances of Android phones in same application

Tags: android, ipc, distributed-computing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Communication between 2 Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860177/communication-between-2-android-phones)

I have 2 instances of my application. I want to pass message(file) from phone 1 to phone 2(using HTTP protocol). Phone 2 acknowledges phone1 and starts processing the file. It sends the updated file as a message to phone 1. This should go on forever. Please let me know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
Button btnSend;
EditText edtNo, estMsg;

if(v==btnSend)
{
   SmsManager sm = Smsmanager.getDefault();

   PendingIntent sendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, sendsms.class), 0);

   sm.sendTextMessage(edtNo.getText().toString(), null, edtMsg.getText.toString(), sendIntent, null);
}
```

where you want to set your class name instead of mine **sendsms.class** 
and also nessasarry to set permission(PERMISSION:SENT_SMS) in AndroidMenifest.xml.

Comment: I mean message passing from distributed systems perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send messages via HTTP, you are going to have to have an application running on a server to control message flow. You will not (AFAIK) be able to send messages directly from phone A to phone B using HTTP. You will need to:

> have phone A leave a message on Server ->
>   Server contacts phone B   (using google GCM) ->
>   Phone B retrieves the message from the server

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also saw GCM, but my requirement is without using any server.

Comment: Then Im afraid its not going to happen! :( To use http you would need to have an IP address which your phone does not have.